# Pandas - find value in column based on values from another column and replace date in different column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, if-statement, replace, find

I have a df that looks like below:

```
ID    Name      Supervisor         SupervisorID
1     X         Y                  
2     Y         C                  
3     Z         Y                  
4     C         Y                  
5     V         X
```

What I need is to find SupervisorID. I can find his ID by checking it in column Name and that I will see his ID so if supervisor is Y then I see that in column Name there is Y so his ID id 2. DF should looks like below:

```
ID    Name      Supervisor         SupervisorID
1     X         Y                  2
2     Y         C                  4
3     Z         Y                  2
4     C         Y                  2
5     V         X                  1
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks for help and best regards

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for unique `Name`s, because in real data duplicates:

```
df['SupervisorID']=df['Supervisor'].map(df.drop_duplicates('Name').set_index('Name')['ID'])
print (df)
   ID Name Supervisor  SupervisorID
0   1    X          Y             2
1   2    Y          C             4
2   3    Z          Y             2
3   4    C          Y             2
4   5    V          X             1
```

Comment: Thanks but I got error: "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"